# Angular html binding with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

So I want to use `innerHTML` for a simple template binding. I've crated this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/vI5awH?p=preview and everything works fine.

Now I wanted to include the exact same code in my project but I see no text in the p-tag! If I check the html then this is the output: `<p></p>` No idea why this happens! I'm using angular 2.1.2

Only difference I can spot between the plunkr and my project is the angular version and that I'm using webpack rather then SystemJS in my project

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a problem with angular-polymer integration. See this issue for reference: https://github.com/platosha/angular-polymer/issues/137